# When using a passive STS for authentication in ASP.NET MVC, how can I access the SecurityToken?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, token, wif, sts-securitytokenservice

I have created a simple ASP.NET MVC (4) application, and I am using the passive profile to authenticate against a remote STS. This all works swimmingly, and I am able to access the claims returned from the STS in the `User.Claims` property.

Now, I need to gain access to the SecurityToken itself that was returned from the STS. Where can I access this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the BootstrapToken (WIF 3.5) or BootstrapContext (4.5).

- [Converting Bootstrap Tokens to SAML Tokens](http://www.syfuhs.net/post/2010/09/09/Converting-Bootstrap-Tokens-to-SAML-Tokens.aspx)
- [Using the BootstrapContext property in .NET 4.5](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2012/11/30/using-the-bootstrapcontext-property-in-net-4-5-2/)